# Window freezes (stuck) in angular?

Tags: angular

In angular when user clicks on a search button for the search page and I have added the pagination on a search result, so issue is when search a single data it was stuck or freezes in some time why this type of issue occurs?

Browser: chrome and firefox

My code below:

**TS FILE**

```
/** pagination  */
  pageChanged(value, flag) {
  if (flag === 'true') {
  this.searchForm.get('page').setValue(value.page);
  this.SearchDetails('false');
 }
}
pagnationValue(flag) {
if (flag === 'false') {
  this.searchForm.get('page').setValue('1');
 }
}
```

**HTML FILE**

```
<pagination class="pagination" [totalItems]="totalCount" [(ngModel)]="page" [maxSize]="5" [itemsPerPage]="itemPerPage" 
(pageChanged)="pageChanged($event, 'true')" [align]="true"[boundaryLinks]="true" previousText="last" firstText="1st" lastText="last nextText="next"></pagination>
```

**SearchDetails() Method**

```
  SearchDetails(flag) {
$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
$('#mainCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
if (flag === 'false') {
  this.alerts = [];
}
this.errorMessage = false;
 this.control =  <FormArray>this.mesaiForm.controls.shohinGroup;
 this.control.controls = [];
  this.leaderService.searchListingApi(this.userid, this.searchForm.value).subscribe(details => {
    if (details.success) {
    this.leaderDataDisplay = details.data;
    this.itemPerPage = details.per_page;
    this.totalCount = details.total_count;
    this.leaderDataDisplay.map((params) => {
    this.patchValues(params);
    });
    this.bumonFilterList();
    /** after updating the data message should be display on update case */
    if (flag === 'true') {
      this.alerts = [{
        type: 'success',
        msg: 'success'
      }];
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
      }, 1000);
    }
    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    //  return this.mesaiForm;
  } else {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    this.alerts = [{
      type: 'danger',
      msg: details.message
    }];
  }
  }, error => {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    this.alerts = [{
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'error'
    }];
  });
}
```

Comment: You have to provide us some code

Comment: provided please see it

Comment: What do you mean by 'freez' ?

Comment: stuck on some time when loader loading the data

Comment: Please provide us your `SearchDetails()` method code

Comment: please see above I have provided

Comment: You don't have any errors on F12 console?

Comment: no I don't got any error

Comment: if you got any error in above code please suggest me then I'll resolved that issue @XardasLord